# Why I can not deploy pods and why it shows NOMINATED NODE none?

Tags: kubernetes

I am deploying some apps. I got all the time

```
kubectl get pods -o wide

NAME                                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS          AGE   IP             NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pic-applet-example-anc-pic-66c9cc4df4-xvqkf   0/1     OOMKilled          543 (5m19s ago)   46h   45.234.76.51   mynode23   <none>           <none>
anc-pic-1-6f6f4f8766-4nwms                    0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0                 43h   45.234.76.57   mynode23   <none>           <none>
```

When I looked events,it shows this warning

```
DNSConfigForming  100s (x12084 over 43h)  kubelet  Search Line limits were exceeded, some search paths have been omitted, the applied search line is: default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local xmp.net.intra net.intra eu.net.intra
```

How to see what prevents pods creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DNSConfigForming 100s (x12084 over 43h) kubelet Search Line limits
> were exceeded, some search paths have been omitted, the applied search
> line is: default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
> xmp.net.intra net.intra eu.net.intra

**The above error occurs  when the following condition is met:More than three user-defined search domains are included in the /etc/resolv.conf file on the NGINX Controller host system.You may encounter this message in the following location:The /var/log/messages file**

There can be a maximum of six search domains with Kubernetes. There can only be a maximum of three search domains defined in the /etc/resolv.conf file because CoreDNS creates three search domains at run-time rather than in the file.

**To resolve the issue**:

You can verify that the NGINX Controller host system's /etc/resolv.conf file has no more than three search domains in order to remove this problem.Reducing the number of custom search domains you have established in your node's /etc/resolv.conf file if it exceeds three will fix the problem.

For the modification to take effect in fresh pods after editing your resolv.conf file, you might need to restart the Kubelet and coredns deployment:

**On each node:**

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

On the machine where you run kubectl:

```
kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart deployment coredns
```

**You can refer this  Lumigo [doc](https://lumigo.io/kubernetes-troubleshooting/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff/)  to troubleshoot and resolve the image pull back off and OOM killed errors For further reference you can also refer to this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-dns-config) and the [blog](https://support.d2iq.com/hc/en-us/articles/12928841075476-DNS-warning-Search-Line-limits-were-exceeded-some-search-paths-have-been-omitted) authored by Steven Sylvester.**

Answer (score 1):

For the first pod, you do not have enough memory allocated to the container in the pod, increase its memory resource request and limit.

For the second pod, k8s is not able to pull the docker image mentioned in the container spec of the pod template. Check that image:tag and verify it exists.